problem on createMiddleware when update clerk to the newest
i update my clerkMiddleware to the newest which is not able to use the authMiddleware anymore but when i change it i got problem in my nextjs app the problem looks like this, please help me because im using i18n as my locale in my website
enter image description here
here my middleware.ts
// import { authMiddleware } from "@clerk/nextjs";
import { clerkMiddleware, createRouteMatcher } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";
import createMiddleware from "next-intl/middleware";

const intlMiddleware = createMiddleware({
  locales: ["en", "id"],
  defaultLocale: "id",
});

const isPublicRoute = createRouteMatcher([
  "/:locale",
  "/:locale/about",
  "/:locale/sign-in",
  "/:locale/sign-up",
]);

// export default authMiddleware({
//   beforeAuth: (req) => {
//     return intlMiddleware(req);
//   },

//   publicRoutes: [
//     "/:locale",
//     "/:locale/about",
//     "/:locale/sign-in",
//     "/:locale/sign-up",
//   ],
// });

export default clerkMiddleware((auth, request) => {
  intlMiddleware(request);
  if (!isPublicRoute(request)) {
    auth().protect();
  }
});

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((?!.*\\..*|_next).*)", "/", "/(api|trpc)(.*)"],
};

i already make it but it looks like this
enter image description here
i try to change my clerkMiddleware but the doc not really so usefull
